# How to make a time index in dataframe pandas with 15 minutes spacing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

How to make a time index in dataframe pandas with 15 minutes spacing for 24 hours with out the date format (12\4\2020 00:15)or doing it manually?
example that I only want is 00:15 00:30 00:45.........23:45 00:00 as an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_timedelta` with an array of numbers, here I chose minutes.

```
pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(0, 24*60, 15), unit='min')
#TimedeltaIndex(['00:00:00', '00:15:00', '00:30:00', '00:45:00', '01:00:00',
#                ....
#                '23:45:00'],
#               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: This is a great! Couldn't figure out the unit='min' there when I was trying this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to create dummy dates with your desired time frequency, then just extract them:

```
pd.Series(pd.date_range(
    '1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', freq='15min', closed='left')).dt.time

0     00:00:00
1     00:15:00
2     00:30:00
3     00:45:00
4     01:00:00
        ...   
91    22:45:00
92    23:00:00
93    23:15:00
94    23:30:00
95    23:45:00
Length: 96, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much !